# Using testng project from github to debug

Tags: eclipse, maven, gradle, m2eclipse, gradle-eclipse

I was able to clone `Testng` from `Github` (`https://github.com/cbeust/testng.git`). I have another project in my `eclipse` which has a few test cases that uses `testng` latest version as a `maven` dependency. I'd like to debug a few issues so I'd like to consume the `testng` project that I cloned from github.  The `github` `testng` project that I checked out is not `eclipse` nature. Any idea How do I do that?

Comment: If I understand you well, the question is more how to use a gradle project from a maven project in Eclipse?

Comment: @JulienHerr : Yes, most likely. Or if it has to be gradle how do I get it setup in eclipse?

Comment: The gradle plugin is supposed to be embedded in the latest releases of eclipse (if not, just install it). You should be able to import testng project as a gradle project.